# angular 2 material tab and ngForm

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-material2

I am using angular2 formsModule and [material2 library](https://github.com/angular/material2).

When I'm trying to check the `form`'s validity outside of the `form` tag I get an

> error: Cannot read property 'valid' of undefined

The `form` tag is wrapped into `md-tab` tag, and I noticed that error depended on it.

ERROR:

```
<button (click)="check(fooForm.valid)"></button>
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="One">
        <form (ngSubmit)="save()" #fooForm="ngForm">
            <input name="One"></input>
            <input name="Two"></input>
        </form>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

NO ERROR:

```
<md-tab-group>
    <md-tab label="One">
        <button (click)="check(fooForm.valid)"></button>
        <form (ngSubmit)="save()" #fooForm="ngForm">
            <input name="One"></input>
            <input name="Two"></input>
        </form>
    </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

Does anyone spot what I've been doing wrong?
Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I know fooform is initialized on after view init but your
>   function runes before this life cycle. So I would change my code like
>   this

`check(fooForm)` in html and in js

```
check(fooForm) {
 return fooForm && fooForm.vali
}
```